# System Freeze With numpy / pandas

Tags: python, numpy, memory, pandas, scipy

Configuration:

1. > $uname -a
   >       3.13.0-67-generic #110-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 23 13:24:41 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
2. > model name    : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4300M CPU @ 2.60GHz
3. > RAM : 8GB

Everytime I try running certain numpy/pandas code my system completely freezes. And then I have to forcefully turn to power button off.

These are some line of codes that usually freezes the system:

1. `numpy.subtract(first_array,second_array)`
   , where they are of shape (18000,1)
2. `pandas.read_csv("file.csv")`, where file is of 1.2gb

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: presumably you're running 64-bit python?

Comment: yes, I am running 64 bit python.